# Set up Laravel project to work with multiple domain names

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

[image]

I have successfully configured multiple domains to point to my Laravel 5.1 project

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/Sites/project/public"
  ServerName app.com
  UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/Sites/project/public"
  ServerName app2.com
  UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/Sites/project/public"
  ServerName app3.com
  UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
```

When I go to

`app.com
app2.com
app3.com`

any of them will point to my project and load the log-in screen.

---

## Issue

When I login, regardless when I am from, I kept redirecting my users to

`app.com/dashboard`

---

## Goal

My goal is, any request from

```
app.com  --> log-in --> redirect to --> app.com/dashobard
app2.com --> log-in --> redirect to --> app2.com/dashobard
app3.com --> log-in --> redirect to --> app3.com/dashobard
```

Is this something that I can do on the application layer or web server?

Comment: Why not store the referring domain somewhere and then have them redirect back to whence they came?

Comment: @Adam How do I deal with that in Laravel ? I never done this before.

Comment: Cookies or a Session perhaps?

Comment: If you change the `config/app.php` key `url` to `app2`, it will redirect to app.com or app2.com?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I don't know yet, let me do that now and find out and update you here.

Comment: @Adam : Good idea, I think I should do that.

Comment: @Adam : Another thought that comes into my mind, right now, I have about 100 redirects over my 20 controllers, having to fix all of those redirects base on the sessions, could lead to a nightmare for testing. Do you have any other suggestions that might require NOT to touch tons of codes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you doing the redirect to `/dashboard`? Are you setting the `$redirectTo` in the `LoginController`?

In general you can host multiple domains using something similar to this.

```
Route::domain('{domain}')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index';
});
```

Then in the controller you can get the domain variable and do what you need to return the appropriate domain.

```
public function index($domain) 
{
    return "Welcome to '$domain'";
}
```

Comment: I guess I can do something like that. Is your syntax is 5.1 ? I am 5.1 and only interested in 5.1 for now.

Comment: Can u store how u manage domains ? Like how u would store it and load it back before redirect ?

Comment: @kyo There are multiple ways you can store it. In the past I've used a domains table to store which domains are available, but what's best depends on what the needs of the project are. You might want to look into [Landlord](https://github.com/HipsterJazzbo/Landlord) or packages like it. It helps you host multiple instances of an app in the same DB/Server.